# Getting the sum of all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have a query that is something like the one below. My goal is to add all the 'total_points' and retrieve the single result of the sum of all the rows.

```
SELECT
SUM(
COALESCE(
CASE 
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT `table_1`.views) > 50 OR  COUNT(DISTINCT `table_1`.views) = 50 AND COUNT(DISTINCT `table_1`.views) < 100 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT `table_1`.views) +5
ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT `table_1`.views)
END,0)
+

CASE 
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT `table_2`.views) > 50 OR  COUNT(DISTINCT `table_2`.views) = 50 AND COUNT(DISTINCT `table_2`.views) < 100 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT `table_2`.views) +5
ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT `table_2`.views)
END,0)) AS sum

FROM  `table_1`
LEFT JOIN `table_2`
ON `table_1`.id = `table_2`.id
GROUP BY `table_1`.primary_id
```

This will give me a result of something like this

```
rank  | total_points
1          321
2          111
3          100
4          90         
5          72
6          60
7          45
8          23
9          11
10         5
```

This is my desire results:

```
   sum   |
   838
```

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work.

Comment: it is giving me an error " Invalid use of group function"

Comment: SELECT SUM(Totalpoints) FROM (my query) x;

Comment: I updated my query, check it!

Comment: Your query is almost certainly not getting the results you expect/correct results: `AND` conditions are evaluated before `OR` conditions: whenever you mix an `OR` with _anything_ else **always** use parenthesis.  Give us sample starting data and desired results based on the sample - I'm suspicious of the need for `DISTINCT` here.

Comment: I updated my query, check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(rank, 'Sum') rank, total_points
FROM (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, T1.total_points
      FROM (SELECT COALESCE((CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t1.views) betwnn 50 AND 100 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT t1.views) + 5 ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT t1.views) END) + 
                  (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.views) betwnn 50 AND 100 THEN    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.views) + 5 ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT t2.views) END), 0)  AS total_points
            FROM table_1 t1
            LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
            GROUP BY t1.primary_id
            ORDER BY total_points
          ) AS T1, (SELECT @rank := 0) AS r
      ORDER BY total_points DESC 
    ) AS A
GROUP BY rank WITH ROLLUP
```